# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: c++

Ошибка в коде на 29 строке:

> Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу ...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(double **matr, int size)
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << matr[i][j] << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

double Determinant(double **a,int size)
{
    double det = 0;
    if (size == 1) {
        det = a[0][0];
    }
    if (size == 2) {
        det = a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[0][1] * a[1][0];
    }
    if (size > 2) {
        double **c = new double*[size];
        for (int k = size - 1;k <= size;k++) {
            for (int i = k + 1;i <= size;i++) {
                c[i][k] = a[i][k] / a[k][k];
                for (int j = k + 1;j <= size;j++) {
                    a[i][j] = a[i][j] - (c[i][k] * a[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++)
        det *= a[i][i];
    return det;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите количество неизвестных: ";
    cin >> size;
    double **Matx = new double *[size];
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        Matx[i] = new double[size];
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < size;j++) {
            cin >> Matx[i][j];
        }
    }

    print(Matx, size);

    cout << "Детерминант: " << Determinant(Matx, size) << endl;

    //Удаление
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] Matx[i]; // Удаляем каждый элемент
    }
    delete[] Matx;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В чем причина ошибки?

Comment: Код ваш вообще не собирается: `In function ‘int main()’: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope: double **Matx = new double *[size];`

Comment: Пропустил при публикации кода, уже исправил.

Comment: логично что будет. У Вас там условия `k <= size` и автоматом выход за границы массива.

Comment: Как можно исправить, если поставить `k < size`, то он вообще не зайдет в цикл.

Comment: может откроете формулы и напишете правильно? там явно цикл должен быть с нуля.

Comment: Преобразование выполняется за (n – 1) шагов (n - число строк и столбцов матрицы). На k-том шаге все элементы матрицы, лежащие ниже k-той строки и правее k-того столбца пересчитываются по формуле:
`a[i][j] = a[i][j] - c[i][k]a[k][j]`, где `c[i][k] = a[i][k] / a[k][k]`
`(i = k+1, k+2, …, n;       j = k+1, k+2, …, n)`
В результате данного преобразования получается матрица, со¬держащая ниже главной диагонали только нулевые элементы. Поэтому ее определитель равен произведению элементов главной диагонали:
`det A = P(от i = 1, до n) a[i][i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Память под строки матрицы `c` в функции `Determinant` нигде не выделяется. Делаетеся только выделение массива указателей

   ```
   double **c = new double*[size];
   ```

   а память под собственно элементы матрицы не выделена. Понятно, что любая попытка доступа к `c[i][j]` будет вызывать падение.
2. В функции `Determinant` внешний цикл в паре

   ```
   for (int k = size - 1;k <= size;k++) {
     for (int i = k + 1;i <= size;i++) {
   ```

   выполнит только две итерации (для `k == size - 1` и `k == size`), а внутренний - только одну итерацию (для `i == size`). Так и задумано?

   При этом доступ по индексам `size` - это доступ за пределами используемых массивов.
3. Отдельно стоить заметить, что матрица `c` в функции `Determinant` уходит в утечку памяти.